# Does this look like termite/carpenter ant leftovers?

Tags: pest-control

I’m in suburban New England. House has had termites a few years ago but had treatment. Noticed this … stuff in the opening near where I had heating system installed. I can’t tell if it’s a sign the bugs are back or just leftover construction debris.

Pics show a shelf in basement storage area and under a shelf in a different area.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clean it up.

If it comes back, it's bugs (well, the first one could also be rodents making a mess above) If it doesn't come back, it's construction leftovers.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you. We did have mice on that first area. Never a dull moment!